# Pandas group by a column and create a dictionary with result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe looks like this

**Input**

```
    NAME         TYPE       GROUP
1   Apple       Source  project1
2   Orange      Target  project1
3   pear        Target  project1
4   pineapple   Target  project1
5   plum        Source  project2
6   pomegranate Target  project3
7   quince      Target  project4
8   raspberry   Source  project3
9   strawberry  Target  project4
```

I need an output of grouping the last column and create a dictionary with the key as source and target as list of values.

To be clear : "Apple" is the source and its targets are "Orange","pear","pineapple" in project-1

**Expected output** :

`{ Apple:["Orange","pear","pineapple"], plum:["pomegranate","quince"],raspberry:["strawberry"] }`

Comment: What if one project has multiple "sources" ?

Comment: it wont have! only one source will be there!

Comment: Why should `plum` cover `quince` value? they are in different projects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that your source DataFrame (with some correction concerning
*GROUP*) is:

```
          NAME    TYPE     GROUP
1        Apple  Source  project1
2       Orange  Target  project1
3         pear  Target  project1
4    pineapple  Target  project1
5         plum  Source  project2
6  pomegranate  Target  project2
7       quince  Target  project2
8    raspberry  Source  project3
9   strawberry  Target  project3
```

Define the following function:

```
def descr(grp):
    src = grp[grp.TYPE == 'Source'].NAME.tolist()[0]
    trg = grp[grp.TYPE == 'Target'].NAME.tolist()
    return pd.Series([src, trg], index=['key', 'value'])
```

Then apply it the following way:

```
df.groupby('GROUP').apply(descr).set_index('key').value.to_dict()
```

The result is:

```
{'Apple': ['Orange', 'pear', 'pineapple'],
 'plum': ['pomegranate', 'quince'],
 'raspberry': ['strawberry']}
```

To analyze how this code works, run it "incrementally", i.e.:

- Start from `df.groupby('GROUP').apply(descr)` - you will get a
  DataFrame - the combined result of *descr* for all gropus.
- Then add `set_index('key')` - you will see this DataFrame with *key*
  as the index.
- And finally add `value.to_dict()` - getting the final result.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Pandas built in `DataFrame.to_dict()` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) it seems like this is what you are looking for.

**EDIT**

I took an alternative approach with the function below that should achieve the same result without using the groupby function. It simply takes in a df as an argument and builds the dictionary you're looking for based by using standard DataFrame filtering.

```
def dictFromDf(df):
    keys = df['Name'][df.Type == 'Source']
    key_group_tuples = []
    for key in keys:
       key_group_tuples.append((key,df.Group[df['Name']== key].values[0]))

    final_dict = {}
    for pair in key_group_tuples:
        final_dict[pair[0]] = list(df.Name[(df.Name != pair[0])
        & (df.Group == pair[1])].values) 

    return final_dict
```

Comment: i can able to create a dict but i cant able to create a condition to match the given output!